# Chrome mobile emulator and iphone doesnt show the same output

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, google-chrome, responsive

I have created calculator for the car rental company.

Problem is, when I check the mobile view (iphone 5 for instance) using chrome inspector, everything looks good, but when I use my Iphone 5, it doesnt show the same design. On my mobile device it doesnt show Rabatt text and doesnt round the price correct.

I have attached screenshots.

I would like to know how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance!
Denis

[image: Iphone (mobile) view]
[image: chrome mobile emulator]

Comment: Emulators are notoriously unreliable. Always test on a device where possible

Comment: Please share your code if you want some help. And for testing either use real devices or use better testing tools like https://www.browserstack.com/ or https://saucelabs.com/